# jquery how to get iframe head value content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an `iframe` and I want to get the head content value.

```
<iframe>
<html>
<head>
<style>body{color:red;}</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="some link">
</head>
</html>
</iframe>
```

I tried this script:

```
var sett_wped_head = jQuery('iframe').contents().find("head").text();
alert(sett_wped_head);
```

but it returns `body{color:red;}`. my goal to get value is

```
<style>body{color:red;}</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="some link">
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** for getting html content inside

```
var sett_wped_head = jQuery('iframe').contents().find("head").html(); 
//                                                       ------^------
alert(sett_wped_head);
```